# ArrowTypeError: Did not pass numpy.dtype object', 'Conversion failed for column X with type int32

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, databricks, pyarrow

#### Problem

I am trying to save a data frame as a parquet file on Databricks, getting the ArrowTypeError.

**Databricks Runtime Version:
7.6 ML (includes Apache Spark 3.0.1, Scala 2.12)**

#### Log Trace

```
ArrowTypeError: ('Did not pass numpy.dtype object', 'Conversion failed for column inv_yr with type int32')
```

Comment: On DBR ML versions it’s better to use versions of  libraries that are already installed there

Answer (score 33, accepted):

The issue you are facing originates from the fact that you are using an old `pyarrow` wheel with the latest `numpy` 1.20 release. You are running into the bug ["PyArray_DescrCheck doesn't work anymore if the consumer library was compiled with an older NumPy version "](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/issues/17913). Either update your `pyarrow` version or downgrade to `numpy<1.20`.

Comment: What is the "lowest acceptable version" for `pyarrow`, that could help getting rid of this error?

Comment: I had to upgrade `pyarrow` to 4.0.1 to avoid this `ArrowTypeError`.